# Pass data to a child route component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I was wondering whether it's possible to pass input data to the component we are loading as a child route, for example, lets say I have this component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'selector',
    templateUrl: 'feature.component.html'
})
export class FeatureComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }
    @Input()
    data: string = "";

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

And in my app I use this component as follows:

But now I would like to load this component as a child route, like this:

```
{ path: 'user/:userid', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
        { path: 'overview', component: FeatureComponent }
    ]
 }
```

And replacing the selector with

```
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Is it possible to deliver the input string to the child route as an input?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: `resolve` in parent route would make sense in this case..

Comment: @PankajParkar, can you link me about your information? I could not seem to understand it

Comment: check out [this](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html) and [this](https://www.codementor.io/max_diachenko/tutorials/angular-2-route-resolves--typescript-du1089pdm) article

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar Resolvers are a really nice way to solve my problem without having to retrieve data twice. Can't thank you more :).